# Naming a polyhedron with 6 faces and 7 vertices

Tags: polyhedra

As somebody who has to interpret different types of polyhedra in his research it is sometimes difficult to find a good name for a polyhedron that describes the coordination in a crystal structure. Luckily we can use concepts like capping and distortion to at least give an idea.

Quite recently a co-worker asked me how we would call a polyhedron where the base and opposite site are not the same polygon. So for an octahedron or a trigonal prism we use a triangular base and top and just turn them to either get the octahedron or the trigonal prism.

But what if both sides do not have the same polygon shapes?

So I searched for examples and all I could really find was a polyhedron that was mentioned in J. Lopez et. Al. *Comput. Phys. Commun.* **2018**, *223*, 45-54.

[image: Example of a polyhedron with 6 faces and 7 vertices [a]]

Source: **DOI**: *10.1016/j.cpc.2017.09.032*

My two questions are, how is the 'category' of polyhedra called where I can find more examples like these? And does this polyhedron have a 'name' or is it characterized by other parameters.

Thank you for all suggestions and ideas,
Best Regards

Comment: @JeanMarie That's because it is a [hexahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexahedron). It has two triangles and four quadrilaterals. This one doesn't seem to have a specific name.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis Thank you very much. I should have paid attention to the termination ...hedron $\ne$ gon.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis I have found [here](http://www.numericana.com/answer/polyhedra.htm) a proposal for a name for this hexahedron: an **hemicube** or a **square hemiprism** by reference to the way of obtention (cube truncation).

Comment: Hemiprism sounds somewhat interesting. Thank you for that website, I will check it out! So judging by how complicated this is it's no common type of polyhedron either, right?

Comment: Indeed, non-regular polyhedra are far less studied than regular or semiregular ones. A thought I had: the process described in the reference above is by **truncation** of an existing polyhedron (a cube). But one could consider your volume as obtained by (also) starting from a cube and **gluing** two of its neighbor vertices...